# storefront not opening in hybris

Tags: docker, sap-commerce-cloud

I followed [this](https://help.hybris.com/6.7.0/hcd/56e101a9178544048ccf7aeb15780d83.html) tutorial

Dockerized Order Management Standalone - B2C

I created files and dockerfile and now docker is up.

```
➜  b2c_oms_dockerized docker ps         
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
105012c1717f        b2c_oms_dockerized_platform   "/opt/startup/startu…"   About an hour ago   Up 23 minutes       0.0.0.0:9002->8088/tcp   b2comsdockerized_platform_webservices_1
84de8dc2b918        b2c_oms_dockerized_hsql       "/opt/hsqldb/start.sh"   About an hour ago   Up 23 minutes       9090/tcp                 b2comsdockerized_hsql_1
```

then I put my custom files inside hybris folder.

i can go to `https://localhost:9002/console/flexsearch`

but I cant go to `http://apparel-de.local:9001/trainingstorefront/`

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: what is the error you are getting when you go to `http://apparel-de.local:9001/trainingstorefront/` ?

Comment: Try - https://apparel-de.local:9002/trainingstorefront/?site=apparel-de

Comment: Is `apparel-de.local` listed in your `hosts` file ?

Comment: yes @JohnnyKonfetti as 127.0.0.1   'localhost electronics.local apparel-uk.local apparel-de.local'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the step number 3?

**docker-compose up -d platform_admin_init**

This command runs the hybris system initialization and sets your system up for initial use. Please do note that this step should be run only once, that is while setting up your system.

Running system initialization on a system that is already set up purges all the existing data.